# JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize() returns null

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON object gotten from a response into an object, but I keep getting null. I'm not sure why that is the case, here is my code:

```
 private static object DeserializeObj(string json)
    {
        object obj = null;
        try
        {
            obj = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize(json, typeof(object));
            
        }
        catch
        {
            Logger.Error("Failed to deserialize JSON");
        }

        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using the (ancient) `JavaScriptSerializer` type?

Comment: Show us the value of `string json`.

Comment: When you log that an exception occurred but not any of its details it makes it harder to diagnose such an issue.

Comment: @Dai what is a better option? Also the value of the string is {"count":20665,"company":"name","emissions":[{}, {}, {}]"}

Comment: @Zyko C#/.NET is not like JavaScript: you can't just deserialize arbitrary JSON into an `Object`: you need to define a `class` that corresponds to the JSON first.... or use something like `JObject`.

Comment: Are you using Net6?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with clarifications asked for in comments.

Comment: In order to help you, we need to see a [mcve], specifically the json which causes the problem.  The full `ToString()` output the exception which you catch and ignore, including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s) if any, would help also.  See [ask].